# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar el sufijo de un string?

Tags: java, netbeans, eclipse

Quería implementar un método el cuál recibe un array de `String`como parámetro y devuelve un nuevo array del mismo tipo y con el mismo tamaño que el pasado como parámetro. El array resultante contendrá las mismas palabras que el original, excepto aquellas que terminan en la palabra indicada, que se modificará eliminando ese subfijo

```
public static String[] palabras (String[] array) {

    String search = "mente";
    for (String i:array) {
        if (i.equals(search)) {     // Al principio lo tenía de la forma (i == search)
            array = array.endswith(i, 0, array.length); // endwiths(valor, inicio, fin)
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según entiendo, lo que quieres es quitar el sufijo en cada una de las palabras del array.

Al iterar en el array, debes comprobar el sufijo (`endsWith()`) en cada palabra, en lugar de hacerlo en el propio array ([hasta donde yo se](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html), los arrays no tienen método `endswith`). Esta debe ser la condición, en lugar de buscar que la palabra sea igual al sufijo

> `if (i.equals(search)) {     // Al principio lo tenía de la forma (i == search)`

ya que esto sólo se cumplirá cuando ambras palabras sean exactamente iguales, y no cuando la palabra contenga al sufijo al final.

```
public static String[] palabras (String[] array, String suffix) {

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i].endsWith(suffix)) {
            array[i] = array[i].substring(0, array[i].length() - suffix.length());
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lo que podrías intentar es evaluar el sufijo y luego modificar tu array. Te presento el siguiente ejemplo.

```
public class Main{

public static  boolean hasSuffix(String word, String suffix){
    if( suffix.length() > word.length()) return false;

    int i = word.length() - 1;
    int j = suffix.length() - 1;
    for( ; i >= 0 && j >=0 ; i--,j--){
        if(word.charAt(i) != suffix.charAt(j) ) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public static String subString(String word, int init, int end){
    String result ="";
    for(int i = init; i < end ;i++){
        result += word.charAt(i);
    }
    return result;
}

public static String[] palabras(String search, String[] array) {

    for( int i = 0; i < array.length ; i++){
        if (hasSuffix(array[i],search)) {    
            array[i] =  subString(array[i],0, array[i].length() - search.length());
        }
    }
    return array;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String array[] = {"jorge","robert","maribel","carlos","joel"};
    String search = "el";

    String result[] = palabras(search,array);

    for( int i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
       System.out.print(result[i] + " "); 
    }
}}
```

Espero te ayude :)